# Discord.JS music bot instantly disconnects

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord Music Bot (discord.js), but everytime the bot connects to the channel to play music it disconnects instantly.

This is the tutorial I have followed: https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/dicord-music-bot

There are not any errors and the ffmpeg is installed.

I am running the bot on a centos 8 VPS, and I have other bots that work fine (not music ones xD)

Answer (score 0):

In the **play function**, delete the line that contains `serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();`.

```
function play(guild, song) {
   const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
   if (!song) {
   serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
   queue.delete(guild.id);
   return;
   }
}
```

The resulting code should like this:

```
function play(guild, song) {
   const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
   if (!song) {
   queue.delete(guild.id);
   return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can setTimeout for this

```
if (!song) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
      }, 300000);
    }
```